# Can I set up a rule so that all bounced emails still show up in my bucket for Amazon SES?

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, smtp, amazon-ses

Edit: To clarify what I was trying to do, I want all received emails to my SES domains to be saved a bucket, even if there is no email inbox to receive the email, instead of sending a bounce message to the sender. Answered below.

I've created an Amazon SES account, verified my domain name and I have set it up to forward emails to an S3 bucket. I am able to send emails from my domain and they appear just fine, but when I receive emails, they do not appear in my S3 bucket. Instead I get bounce saying the mail is undeliverable:

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

     test@XX.XXXXX.com

Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain XXXX.XXXX.com by feedback-smtp.us-west-2.amazonses.com. [54.240.249.182].

The error that the other server returned was:
550 Mailbox does not exist!
```

I would like all emails that are received (whether or not the mailbox exists) to go to my S3 bucket, and not send bounce messages. Is this possible? It sounds like I may need to set up an inbox, but does SES allow me to create one that is a global/wildcard mailbox that just receives all emails? I'm going to parse the responses myself so I don't need or want a mail client to handle parsing the emails.

Edit : To clarify : XXXX.com is my domain name, not an external domain. So I am sending an email from gmail to a verified domain name that I control, with MX records pointing to SES. I realize that of course if I send an email to a non existent email address at another domain it will bounce; the question is why it is bouncing off of an SES domain under my control.

Edit2: I found a workaround. If I remove the domain name from my ruleset so that ALL domains go to the same S3 bucket, it works as expected: The email goes to the S3 bucket, and no bounce email is sent.

Comment: You should answer your own question. That's a really nice approach to generic mailboxes that can be used to a lot of things. Congrats!

Comment: Even though you solved it, I feel like this question needs some editing to express what you were actually trying to accomplish, for the benefit of future visitors.  Of course you don't really want "bounced" emails to be saved, since that's a contradiction in terms, but rather that you want them not to bounce.  Docs: ["On the Recipients page, choose Next Step. Because you aren't adding any recipients, this receipt rule will handle mail for all recipients in all of your verified domains."](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-getting-started-receipt-rule.html)

Answer (score 0):

Per suggestion in the comments, I'm answering the question with my own solution. If you create a receipt rule with a blank domain (so it covers all domains) that goes to an S3 bucket, the emails show up as expected. The rulesets are documented here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-getting-started-receipt-rule.html